# Uniform Integrability - sufficient condition and bounded convergence theorem with weaker hypothesis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

1. How does the result follow? Do we choose $K = (\frac{\varepsilon}{A})^{\frac{1}{1-p}}1_{A \ne 0}$

---

[image]

---

2. Why do we have that inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, we can choose such a $K$, or just notice that $$\lim_{K\to +\infty}K^{1-p}A=0$$ and that the bound of $\mathbb E\left(\left|X\right|;\left|X\right|\gt K\right)$ is uniform with respect to $X\in\mathcal C$.
2. The follows from the inclusion 
   $$\left\{\left|X\right|\gt K+k^{-1}\right\}\subset \left\{\left|X-X_n\right|\gt k^{-1}\right\}.$$ 
   To see this, it suffices to show that 
   $$\left\{\left|X-X_n\right|\leqslant k^{-1}\right\}\subset \left\{\left|X\right|\leqslant K+k^{-1}\right\}.$$
   If $\omega$ is such that $\left|X(\omega)-X_n(\omega)\right|\leqslant k^{-1}$, then by assuption, 
   $$\left|X(\omega)\right|\leqslant \left|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\right|+\left|X(\omega)\right|\leqslant k^{-1}+K.$$

Comment: just realised A could be zero. anyhoo thanks davide giraudo ^-^